# Updating Default Branch - GitHub GraphQL API

Tags: github-api

I’m trying to update the default branch for a repository using the GutHib v4 API, but having trawled through the documentation there doesn’t seem to be a mutation available to do this.

I have the current default branch ID from querying the repository properties.

I assumed it would be under updateRepository, but that’s quite high level and I can’t see any other obvious options available to do this.

I assume they won’t have missed adding this functionality so I guess I’m just looking in the wrong places.

Has anyone done this before or have an idea where the mutation might sit?

Comment: Do workaround of using GitHub API v3 is an option?

Comment: That’s what I’ve done for now, though I was hoping for a complete migration to v4 (this work is taking an existing app running against v3 and moving it to v4).

Comment: yeah, I got you. As I checked also, it looks like they don't have the option of updaing a new default branch at v4